# haproxy configuration

Tags: networking

I cant get my Haproxy to come online....when i do service haproxy start i get fatal errors
my setup
i installed haproxy
then install heartbeat...
i only want to have one nlb and two web servers (windows). do i need heartbeat still?? i added eth0:0 with VIP - 10.4.3.56 when i try to start the haproxy with cfg -

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1   local0
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
        #log loghost    local0 info
        maxconn 4096
        #debug
        #quiet
        user haproxy
        group haproxy

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        redispatch
        maxconn 2000
        contimeout      5000
        clitimeout      50000
        srvtimeout      50000

listen webfarm 10.4.3.56:80
       mode http
       stats enable
       stats auth someuser:somepassword
       balance roundrobin
       cookie JSESSIONID prefix
       option httpclose
       option forwardfor
       option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
       server webA 10.4.3.52:80 cookie A check
    server webB 10.4.3.53:80 cookie B check
```

i cant get it to start please advise...

Answer (score 2):

With only one load balancer, I wouldn't think you would have any need for heartbeat.

For the 'haproxy will not start' problem, the listening address of

> webfarm 10.4.3.56:80

is likely the virtual address of the web farm you're trying to create.  Since the IP is not bound to a local adapter (because you're not running heartbeat to create this virtual IP), haproxy will not start.  Use an IP that exists on the host, or use:

> webfarm 0.0.0.0:80

After HAProxy starts, point a browser to the IP address of the host running HAProxy.  You should receive results from your two web servers.